# How would to show form validation errors with django single fields?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've to put in the fields of the form individually because for me its a little easier to style, my issue is that I can't seem to get it to display the error messages on validation. The form validates correctly, it just doesnt show what errors I get when I do get an error, instead it just doesnt submit. How can I fix this?

Template:

```
    <form  action="#" method="post"> {%csrf_token%} {{form.management_form}}



    {%for f in form%} 
    {{ f.non_field_errors }}


    <div class="row">

   <div class="medium-3 columns ">
   <label> First Name
   {{ member_fname.errors }}
    {{f.member_fname}}
  </label>
    </div>

  <div class="medium-3 columns ">
    <label> Last Name
      {{ member_lname.errors }}

        {{f.member_lname}}
   </label>
  </div>

  <div class="medium-3 columns ">
   <label> Email
      {{ member_email.errors }}

      {{f.member_email}}
   </label>
 </div>

<div class="medium-3 columns ">
<label> Phone #
   {{ member_phone.errors }}

    {{f.member_phone}}
</label>
</div>

 </div>
 <hr/>
 {%endfor%}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="small-3 columns small-centered">
 <button type="submit" class="button medium radius"> submit</button>
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for rendering validation errors:

```
{{ form.fieldname.errors }}
```

This will show validation errors in a list format and if you want to render them as text then use:

```
{{ form.fieldname.errors.as_text }}
```